# <h:commandLink action="#{bean.preparePreview}" is not working

Tags: jsf

```
<h:commandLink action="#{bean.preparePreview}" onclick="window.open('../note/note.faces', 'popupWindowName', 'dependent=yes, menubar=no, toolbar=no, height=450, width=700');return false;">
```

In above code action is not invoked. only pop is shown. 
Can you help me what is the problem?

Comment: Hi, maybe this thread will help you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-is-not-being-invoked

Comment: One line of code may not help us to solve your problem. Please provide us some more snippet.

Comment: Not needed, the problem is in this line, as stated by `BalusC`

Answer (score 3):

You've a `return false;` in the end of the onclick function. This will cause that the element's default action won't be invoked. So remove it or rearrange your logic to open the window in the target page only.